# Pronoun agreement: His and my house vs Our house

Tags: possessive-pronouns

Would "her and my" be plural?

I know that "Sue and I moved into *our* house" is correct PN agreement.

But wouldn't "Sue and I moved into *her and my* house"?

I know it's awkward but wouldn't the "and" instead of "or" make the phrase "her and my" a compound object which agreed with the compound subject?

Comment: It's not a compound *subject* here (that honour belongs to *Sue and I*), but it *is* both a compound and grammatical.

Answer (score 1):

Did you both move into the same house? In that case the house is singular.

"Her and my" or "our" are possessive adjectives. Either expression would be grammatically correct. As a matter of usage, if Sue is your wife, for example, then it would be usual to say "our". If Sue is merely an acquaintance, and each of you part owns the house, then "her and my" could be used, to indicate that you are two separate individuals who happen to co-own a house, rather than an item.

Did she move into her house and you move into yours? In that  case there is more than one house and so you should say "houses". in that case the usual expression would be to say: "Sue and I moved into our respective houses".

Comment: Thanks.  That makes perfect sense.  I don't know what my status is with Sue.  I wish she would just move out and leave me with the house.